# Which distances k-means pre-computes when precompute_distances is set to True?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means, computational-geometry, euclidean-distance

I am using scikit-learn to run k-means. I looked the scikit-learn k-means code but  I don't understand how k-means pre-computes distances in advance. Which distances k-means pre-computes in advance while it doesn't know in advance the values of the centers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not pre-compute the distance between the centers, it precomputes the distance between a point, say X and all other points in the system and stores them for later use.

Check this [line 619 in kmeans](http://%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20_labels_inertia_precompute_dense(X,%20x_squared_norms,) which calls `_labels_inertia_precompute_dense`, which in turn calls [pairwise_distances_argmin_min at line 562](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b464d094d2c468a16ea9f8bf8d42d949f84/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py#L562).

The documentation of [pairwise_distances_argmin_min](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances_argmin_min.html) states that

> Compute minimum distances between one point and a set of points.
>   This function computes for each row in X, the index of the row of Y
>   which is closest (according to the specified distance). The minimal
>   distances are also returned.

So it does not need to know the centres, this is just used to precompute distances between all possible pair of points with each other.

Comment: Thank you. Ok, It pre-computes the distances between points of the data set. But in which cases these pre-computed distances are used in k-means?

Comment: When you want to use a distance function that isn't implemented in scikit-learn or you have a quicker implementation.

Comment: @ncfirth tke scikit-learn k-means pre-computes distances between points of the dataset in advance. How theses distances are used during the scikit-learn k-means execution?

Comment: Ah forgive me, I've confused the question to be about Kernel methods rather than regular KMeans.

Comment: @MohammedKashif I voted but I think it is not displayed because I have less 15 reputations. Can you answer about this question: How the pre-computed distances are used during the scikit-learn k-means execution?

Comment: @pedrocolombino you need to click on the tick mark next to the answer to accept it. Also, these pre-computed distances are helpful because you don't need to find the centres, and the nearest points to these centres. You save up computational time to find these distnaces.

Comment: @MohammedKashif I dont' understand your answer about pre-computed distances. How can we avoid to find centers while we need to find the closest center for each point. Have you any formula to find center with only pre-computed distances?